# How to get git diff between two refs in Gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am running a `GitLab CI script` when user pushing the code. In this CI, I would like to find the `git diff` between two refs.

ex: `git diff --name-only $old_ref $new_ref`

How to do that in GitLab? or any related commands or document will be helpful.

Comment: Can we safely assume you already checked [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/diffs.html) extensively?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not check this. Can I have an example script?. I am new to GitLab. So, I could not understand how to use `Gitlab::Git::Diff.between` APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get the very recent committed files list by using this command in GitLab

`git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}`  and

`git show --name-only`  command shows details along with commit message.

Answer (score 0):

one solution in this instance would most likely be a [gitlab hook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/custom_hooks.html).

by using a hook, you can then use your `git diff` command to calculate based on the previous and current hash.